# How to apply element-wise multiplication to two CArrays in haskell?

Tags: arrays, haskell

Like I got a `CArray` `[1,2,3]` and a `CArray` `[6,7,8]`, I want to multiply element by element and get `[6, 14, 24]`. Could you give me a demo. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Stackoverflow.com is a community site where people, put in time and effort to help each other. Please show some effort on your side and tell us what you have tried and or what problem you specifically cannot solve.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I haven't answered any question now. I'm just a freshman of stackoverflow and I will help ohters in the future.

Comment: it's no problem that you did not answer any question yet - the problem is that you did not show anything besides a quick question right here - so maybe you should add what you did try or what exactly you are missing to help you out

Comment: I have found a function in Data.Matrix called elementwise to apply on the element of the two matrix element by element. So I just want to know whether there is such function in Data.Array.CArray. And I have search the document but don't get any valid information.

Answer (score 5):

While I am not familiar with `CArray` at all, just looking at the function types in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/carray-0.1.6.1/docs/Data-Array-CArray.html is enough to see the answer: `liftArray2 (*) arr1 arr2` (assuming `arr1` and `arr2` have the same index and value type).